# Oracle analytical SQL - Retrieve the start, end and step of a range

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to use the Oracle analytical functions to neatly retrieve the range of a number of rows. (I guess mainly the LAG and LEAD functions here.)

For example: I have the following values: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 14

I'm looking to retrieve the values as the following rows in an elegant way.

| Start_Value | End_Value | Step |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 7 | 1 |
| 9 | 12 | 3 |
| 14 | NULL | NULL |

See below for table creation scripts:

```
create table temp_data
(
    data_value number(16,4)
);
insert into temp_data values(-2);
insert into temp_data values(-1);
insert into temp_data values(0);
insert into temp_data values(1);
insert into temp_data values(2);
insert into temp_data values(3);
insert into temp_data values(5);
insert into temp_data values(6);
insert into temp_data values(7);
insert into temp_data values(9);
insert into temp_data values(12);
insert into temp_data values(14);
```

Below is my very complex SQL, which sort of works, but is impossible to read, and really ugly.

```
select start_value, 
       case when start_value = end_value then null else step end as step,
       case when start_value = end_value then null else end_value end as end_value
from
(
    select case when row_number > 1 then start_value + step else start_value end as start_value, step, end_value
    from
    (
        select data_value as start_value, next_step as step, lead(data_value) over (order by data_value) as end_value, rownum as row_number
        from
        (
            select data_value, next_step, prev_step
            from
            (
                select data_value, data_value - prev_value as prev_step, next_value - data_value as next_step
                from
                (
                    select data_value, lead(data_value) over (order by data_value) as next_value, lag(data_value) over (order by data_value) as prev_value
                    from
                    (
                        select distinct data_value
                        from   temp_data
                        order by data_value
                    )
                )
            )
            where prev_step is null
            or next_step is null
            or prev_step <> next_step
        )
    )
)
where start_value is not null;
```

It will retrieve the result as belows:

| Start_Value | End_Value | Step |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | 7 | 1 |
| 9 | NULL | NULL |
| 12 | NULL | NULL |
| 14 | NULL | NULL |

My question is simply, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution to this.  How do you know that your results are not `-2/2/1, 3/5/2, 6/7/2, . . . `?  That is, there is more than one representation for what you are asking for.

Comment: Your examples seem to have many mistakes in them. For example: in the first "output" table, the steps are 1, 1, 3 and NULL. Are they supposed to be 1, 2, 3 and NULL? And, if the inputs are ...6, 7, 9, 12, 14 why do you show a "range" from 9 to 12? The CREATE script doesn't have the value 9 but it does have the value 10. Etc. Please clean up your examples, then we can talk. (Also, why do you want to show the last step as NULL, and not as a number like the other steps?)

Comment: Also, what is your Oracle version? If my guess is correct, that you want to show sequences of consecutive integers, this has a very elegant solution in older versions, using analytic functions (SUM, not LEAD/LAG), with a method known as "Tabibitosan method" - and a **much** more elegant solution in Oracle 12.1 and higher, using MATCH_RECOGNIZE.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes there are more than 1 representations and that's fine. Any valid representations are fine. The real situation would have been much tidier than these test data.

Comment: @mathguy The steps and input are both correct. The only thing wrong was the value 10 in the create script. It should be a 9. I've corrected that now. There are multiple representations here. So I can have a single 9, 12, 14, OR I can have a 9 with step 3, and a single 14, OR I can have a single 9, then a 12 with step 2. The purpose of the exercise is to simply make sure that all ranges in the raw data are retrieved and arranged properly.

Comment: @mathguy I am using Oracle 12. Thanks for the Tabibitosan method. That looks promising. Will do some reading tonight..

Comment: I see now. Tabibitosan will not help in this problem (although you might indeed want to read about it for other uses). MATCH_RECOGNIZE will very likely help. Also, the problem **can** be formulated in a deterministic way; I will explain in my Answer when I get a chance to write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be formulated in a deterministic way, as follows:

Order the values in ascending order. Take the first two values (the two smallest ones), compute the difference, call it "step". Consider these two values as the first two in a possibly longer arithmetic progression (constant step between each pair of consecutive numbers). Stop the "range" as long as the next step is different from the previous one. Take note of the first value, the last value and the step for this "range".

Then, repeat for the remainder of the values in the table.

In the end, if there is exactly one value left (so you can't really "repeat"), declare that this last value is the "start", the end and the step are NULL, and we are done.

The fact that in each case we don't "stop" a range until we must is what makes this problem statement deterministic.

This can be expressed almost directly in MATCH_RECOGNIZE, as shown below.

```
select *
from   temp_data
match_recognize(
  order    by data_value
  measures a.data_value                       as start_value,
           last(b.data_value)                 as end_value,
           first(b.data_value) - a.data_value as step
  pattern  ( a b* )
  define   b as
             data_value - prev(data_value) = first(b.data_value) - a.data_value
);

START_VALUE  END_VALUE       STEP
----------- ---------- ----------
         -2          3          1
          5          7          1
          9         12          3
         14
```

**EDIT**

*(* ***NOTE:*** *An earlier edit, which I have now deleted, gave an incorrect solution using analytic functions. If anyone wants to see it, that is still possible, by following the "Edited" link at the bottom.)*

Here is a different solution, using the recursive subquery factoring feature added in Oracle 11.2. It essentially mimics what `match_recognize` does. The `CLS` column created in the recursive subquery corresponds to the `CLASSIFIER()` function in `match_recognize`, and `GRP` corresponds to `MATCH_NUMBER()`. However, one doesn't need to know anything about `match_recognize` to understand the recursive solution shown below.

```
with
  p (rn, val) as (
    select row_number() over (order by data_value), data_value from temp_data
  )
, r (rn, val, step, cls, grp) as (
    select  1, val, null, 'A', 1
      from  p
      where rn = 1
    union all
    select  p.rn, p.val, p.val - r.val,
            case when r.cls = 'A' or p.val = r.val + r.step 
                 then 'B' else 'A' end,
            case when r.cls = 'A' or p.val = r.val + r.step 
                 then r.grp else r.grp + 1 end
      from  p join r on p.rn = r.rn + 1
  )
select min(val) as start_value, 
       max(case cls when 'B' then val end) as end_value,
       min(case cls when 'B' then step end) as step
from   r
group  by grp
order  by grp
;
```

Comment: I think there's an issue here with the Oracle 11 query. In the final boundaries table, you were using the odd row as the start value and even row as the end value. This essentially means that the even rows will be the start value, which is incorrect. Take the example of 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9. The boundaries table will contain 3 rows: 0 - 3, 3 - 9, and a single 9. When pivoted, it would output the value as 0 -3 and 9, therefore omitting the 3-9 range.

Comment: @Samuel - with those inputs there should be only two ranges, 0-3 and 5-9. You are right though - the logic I used is incorrect, in the case when the last number of the first "range" **could** also be part of the second range. Here the "step" from 3 to 5 is 2, equal to the step in the second range. Good catch! A lot of participants here don't test our solutions carefully enough, and sometimes they accept solutions that are in fact wrong. My analytic functions solution is wrong. I'll give it some thought to see if I can fix it; in any case, I'll put a note in the Answer.

Comment: the last bit of query can be changed to use the LEAD function to get the end value, and use the start_value + step as the step value for row number >= 2. The only problem with that is it would give me 3 ranges: 0-3, 5, 7-9 (just like my initial query). Not ideal but at least it works..

Comment: @Samuel - I don't believe there is a reasonable solution using analytic functions alone, that would give the correct output in all cases, if we require the "standardized" output I described in my answer. (Meaning, require each successive range to be as long as possible - don't cut a range into a union of smaller ranges, when not required by the data). Instead, I will show a different solution using recursive subquery factoring.